# HTML style tag in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Below is valid html that works in Codepen, but doesn't in a JupyterLab IPython notebook cell.

```
<h3 style="color: red; font-family: Helvetica; line-height: 2"> What was the first day an agent did not receive any calls? </h3>
```

Any suggestions on why or how to make it work?

**UPDATE**

I am writing the above code in a markdown cell.

There is no error message. It just doesn't color the heading red as indicated in the markdown code.

Comment: Please provide more details and steps to reproduce, for example: what kind of cell do you try to embed this code in (code, markdown)? How do you embed this code (display function, string, in markdown)? Is there any error message?

Comment: @krassowski I have provided an update. Thank you.

Comment: This works for me. Which JuptrerLab version do you use?

Comment: @krassowski Where do I find the version?

Comment: @krassowski  I am using version 0.32.1

Comment: Have you tried `<h3 style="color: red!important; font-family: Helvetica; line-height: 2"> What was the first day an agent did not receive any calls? </h3>`? I am running 1.0 alpha. Maybe update to 0.35.4 (lastest stable) would help?

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1812

Answer (score 1):

Support for inline styles was introduced in JupyterLab 0.35, relevant changlog part:

- Allow safe inline CSS styles in Markdown. ([#5012](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/5012), [#1812](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1812))

Please try upgrading to the latest stable version (0.35.4 as per today).

As the styles are passed through sanitizer, some of your styles may be removed (the authors try to be on the safe side when it comes to potential security vulnerabilities) - if this is the case, double-check that you have no typos and look up the list of allowed styles in [sanitizer.ts](https://github.com/biermeester/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/apputils/src/sanitizer.ts) (look for `allowedStlyes`) to check if the style you wish to use is allowed.

Comment: Thank you. How do I update JupyterLab. When I try to do it directly from Anaconda, it gives me this error - `Multiple errors encountered`.

Comment: Unless you use Windows x32, you should be able to install newest JupyterLab from conda-forge channel. You may want to ask a new question providing complete details (the command you used, conda info, conda list). Also, this issue https://github.com/conda-forge/jupyterlab-feedstock/issues/151 suggests that there might be problems with the newest version on Windows. Maybe try installing 0.35.3?